# Force fragment in viewpager reload adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have `viewpager` below:  [image]

Each view will load a list view which is stored in `sqlite`. In each `item` of list view haves a button to change itself to other list by making a change in DB.
**For example**: i can move item in `List fragment` to `Absen fragment` or `Atten fragment`

**The problem** is that the view of **the middle fragment** not reload. I think because my `adapter` not call (because `the fragment` is in the middle so it already is called in `previous fragment`).
My fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_student_current_session, container,false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        setListViewAdapter();

        return view;
    }

    public void setListViewAdapter(){
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        list = db.getListStudentAbsen(((CurrentSessionActivity)this.getActivity()).getSessionID());

        listView.setAdapter(new ListAbsenStudentCurrentSessionAdapter(list, getActivity()));
    }
```

Is this implement is correct or i should try use other to interact with DB such as only update db when the `activity` is totally finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for my case by using this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed) {
        //call set adapter here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what happens on in your program. But as I could understand **Litst view item** in first **ViewPager item** can update itselft and then it should appear in second **ViewPager item**? If it so you should get instance of second **ViewPager item** with pagerAdapter.getItem(position) and then call something like setData(list) -> notifyDataSetChanged()

For example you have 3 fragments in PagerAdapter each fragment has its own list view, and when data in first fragment's list updates you have to update second's fragment list adapter.

Comment: how i can get `instance` of the second fragment when in other fragment?

Comment: You have to create interface in this fragment (for example ItemChangeListener) then implement it in Main fragment where ViewPager is. Then in current fragment call interface method. In Main fragment inreface implementation you can get instance of second fragment

Comment: you mean i implement ItemChangeListener in the parent activity (moreover my list is retrieve from DB, is it okay to call notifyDataSetChanged)

Comment: There where your ViewPager is. If it is Activity then - yes.